# Declaring multiple cariables in JavaScript in comparison to Python

Tags: javascript, python

In python you can declare variables like this

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

Can you do the same think in JS, where you have two variable names seperated by a komma and then two values seperated by a komma? Just like this:

```
let a, b = 1, 2
```

Comment: use `let a=1, b=2` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign directly

```
let a = 1, b = 2;
```

or use a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with an array.

```
let [a, b] = [1, 2];
```